# Variable mysteriously being evaluated to nil

Tags: xcode, swift, nstimer

I'm trying to set up a view controller in Xcode where a label is updated by an NSTimer. Some of the code that I used is below:

```
var secondsCounter = 0
var minutesCounter = 0
var timer = NSTimer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timer.invalidate()

    // start the timer
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}    
func timerAction() {
    secondsCounter += 1
    if secondsCounter >= 60 {
        secondsCounter -= 60
        minutesCounter += 1
    }
    if secondsCounter < 10
    {
        secondsLabel.text = "0" + "\(secondsCounter)"
    }
    else {
        secondsLabel.text = "\(secondsCounter)"
    }
    minutesLabel.text = "\(minutesCounter)"

}
    //MARK: Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var minutesLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var secondsLabel: UILabel!
```

I kept getting the error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on the line that was trying to update the text in the seconds label. I don't understand why this wasn't working, as I have another view controller with the exact same code that works perfectly. I tweaked a few things and stopped getting the error, but secondsCounter is still coming out to nil as the label only shows the "0". I've been trying to fix this for hours to no avail. I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: your IBOutlet is ok? maybe secondsLabel = nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

- Putting outlets before method
- Checking that the outlets are connected
- Check that the outlet name in the storyboard is the same as in the code

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that the outlets for secondsLabel and minutesLabel were connected to the same label in the storyboard.